# Python unicode left tor right

Tags: python, unicode

I am fiddling around with Python and unicode, I am reading from some files and then want to do a right to left unicode character and then switch it back afterwards. However, I am running into some problems.

My code is as follows:

```
var_1=u"\u202E"
var_2="u\u202D"

print("123 "+var_1+"abc")
print("123 "+var_2+var_1+"abc "+var_2+"ABC")
```

What I am trying to make the second print say is essentially 123 cba ABC, however, it yields

```
123 cba
123 uABCu cba
```

First of all I am fairly puzzled why the u's appear, second of all I am just looking to cancel out the var_1 unicode after abc. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you [edit] the exact output from "it yields 'xxx'" into your post and format it as code?

Comment: Does bidi depend on the terminal? How are you viewing the output?

Comment: You appear to have a typo in the assignment to `var_2`; the `u` is inside the quotes, not outside.

Comment: Ah yeah thanks, completely missed that! Output is now 123 ABC cba